# Reduce down level of multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I'm wondering what the most efficient way to reduce this array down by a level, ideally without loops in PHP. It's a result from mysqli_fetch_all().

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 648546
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 648552
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 650046
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 652732
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 652738
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 652756
        )

)
```

The result I would like is

```
array(648546,648552,650046,652732,...)
```

The simple query example it comes from is something as easy as:

```
SELECT mytable.ID FROM mytable WHERE status =1
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the SQL query that produces the result. You may be able to use GROUP_CONCAT to produce the result without loops.

Comment: @SloanThrasher Example query added.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This should do it for PHP 5.5+](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

```
$result = array_column($array, 'ID');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$new_array = array_map(function($v){return $v['ID'];}, $old_array);
```

Answer (score 2):

You might try this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(mytable.ID)
FROM mytable 
WHERE status = 1
GROUP BY status
```

It should return 1 row with the ID as a comma separated list.

Comment: There is a server defined maximum length of a `GROUP_CONCAT` column. By default I think it's 1,024 characters, so if you have more than  150(ish) 6 digit IDs this won't work.

Comment: not pure PHP, but still a fanstastic answer which has also equally solved the problem!

Comment: If you need more than 1024 characters for the result, you can change the max length for the group concat using ```SET group_concat_max_len = val;```. See [group_concat][https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)